# Downloading multiple pdf files using wget fails (403 error)

Tags: pdf, curl, wget

I'm trying to download multiple pdf files from a web page (I'm using Mac OS X 10.6.1). Here is a example what I'm getting (www.website.org is just for example):

```
~> wget -r -A.pdf http://www.website.org/web/

--2009-10-09 19:04:53--  http://www.website.org/web/
Resolving www.website.org... 208.43.98.107
Connecting to www.website.org|208.43.98.107|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2009-10-09 19:04:54 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

~>
```

How can I overcome this 403 error? Should I use curl instead?

Comment: Can you download this pdf file with your web browser?

Comment: There is multiple pdf files, and I would like to use command line tools for this. My intention is to create batch script to automate some downloads.

Comment: I can use a browser to download files, so there's no problem with that.

Comment: When you download from a browser do you need to login or use a cookie?

Comment: No, just click the name of the file (with mouse 2nd) and start downloading

Comment: THis is the actual webpage: http://www.brinzal.org/guiarapacesnocturnas.html (see links for pdf-files, eg. portada)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you don't have permission to access the directory `http://www.website.org/web/`. Use this link in your web browser and see if you are redirected to a more specific URL. Then use that URL as input for `wget`.